# Iteration through Parent-child with endpoint call

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Scenario: Request consist of multiple orders with details. Send order details to back-end service and get a new Row number that after I should used like one of param with create details

Request looks:

```
<OrderList>
        <Order>
            <target>MySQL</target>
            <Sales>
                <email>p@gmail.com</email>
            </Sales>
            <Details>
                <Item><qty>1</qty><code>PR9</code></Item>
                <Item><qty>2</qty><code>PR8</code></Item>
                <Item><qty>3</qty><code>PR7</code></Item>
            </Details>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <target>MySQL</target>
            <Sales>
                <email>j@gmail.com</email>
            </Sales>
            <Details>
                <Item><qty>4</qty><code>PR6</code></Item>
                <Item><qty>5</qty><code>PR5</code></Item>
                <Item><qty>6</qty><code>PR4</code></Item>
            </Details>
        </Order>
        .......
   </OrderList>
```

sequence:

```
                <inSequence>
            <!--  get source target data -->
            <iterate expression="//Order" preservePayload="true">
                <target>
                        <enrich>
                            <source clone="true" xpath="//Order"/>
                            <target property="OrderBackup" type="property"/>
                        </enrich>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="//target" name="SalesTarget" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="//Sales/email" name="email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <filter regex="MySQL" source="$ctx:SalesTarget">
                            <then>

                                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                                    <format>
                                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                                            <soapenv:Header/>
                                            <soapenv:Body>
                                                <dat:addSalesOrder>
                                                    <dat:email>$1</dat:email>
                                                </dat:addSalesOrder>
                                            </soapenv:Body>
                                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                                    </format>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:email"/>
                                    </args>
                                </payloadFactory>
                                <call blocking="true">
                                    <endpoint key="SalesOrderEP"/>
                                </call>
                                **<enrich>
                                    <source clone="true" type="body"/>
                                    <target property="newRowID" type="property"/>
                                </enrich>**

                                <property expression="$ctx:newRowID > 0 " name="isCorrectResponse" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                                <filter regex="true" source="$ctx:isCorrectResponse">
                                    <then>
                                       <enrich>
                                        <source clone="true" property="OrderBackup" type="property"/>
                                        <target type="body"/>
                                    </enrich>
                                        <iterate expression="//Details">
                                            <target>
                                                <sequence>
                                                    <property expression="//qty" name="qty" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                                    <property expression="//code" name="code" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                                    <log level="custom">
                                                        <property expression="fn:concat('params:Code: ' ,$ctx:code, ' ;Qty: ',$ctx:qty)" name="info"/>
                                                    </log>
                                                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                                                        <format>
                                                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                                                                <soapenv:Header/>
                                                                <soapenv:Body>
                                                                    <dat:addSalesDetails>
                                                                        <dat:salesId>$1</dat:salesId>
                                                                        <dat:qty>$2</dat:qty>
                                                                        <dat:code>$3</dat:code>
                                                                    </dat:addSalesDetails>
                                                                </soapenv:Body>
                                                            </soapenv:Envelope>
                                                        </format>
                                                        <args>
                                                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:newRowID"/>
                                                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:qty"/>
                                                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:code"/>
                                                        </args>
                                                    </payloadFactory>
                                                    <call blocking="true">
                                                        <endpoint key="SalesDetailsEP"/>
                                                    </call>
                                                    <!--  get response and log it  -->
                                                    <aggregate>
                                                        <completeCondition>
                                                            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                                                        </completeCondition>
                                                        <onComplete expression="//m0:UpdatedRowCount/Value" xmlns:m0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                                            <log level="full"/>
                                                            <drop/>
                                                        </onComplete>
                                                    </aggregate>
                                                </sequence>
                                            </target>
                                        </iterate>
                                    </then>
                                    <else/>
                                </filter>
                            </then>
                            <else/>
                        </filter>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
        </inSequence>
```

I have a problem with first call response ... I used

```
<enrich>
      <source clone="true" type="body"/>
       <target property="newRowID" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

to save newly created row Id in property and I'm getting it correctly in line

```
> <log level="custom">
> <property expression="fn:concat('NewRowID = ' ,$ctx:newRowID)" name="info"/>
> </log>
```

BUT when I want to use it  in second payload  it looks it cannot resolve it ?!!?

error:

> DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find
>   parameter with type:query-param name:salesId DS Code:
>   INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

I figure out that in payload the $ctx:newRowID is reolved as

```
  <GeneratedKeys> xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><Entry><ID>93</ID></Entry></GeneratedKeys>
```

and not simply as **93**

I'm guessing this is because in enrich I used source as "body" .. but when I tried to get xpath of response like **xpath = "//Entry/ID"** I got nothing

what is wrong?

Comment: I found a solution to preserve original part of message with <enrich>
                                            <source clone="true" property="OrderBackup" type="property"/>
                                            <target type="body"/>
                                        </enrich> BUT now I have issue to preserve newRowID and send it like part of detail message

Comment: The real question is also WHY when I send call to end point and try to save response in property it wont work ???My response is like <soapenv:Body><GeneratedKeys xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><Entry><ID>106</ID></Entry></GeneratedKeys>    and when I set xpath in enrich like <enrich>                           <source xmlns:n0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" clone="true" xpath="//n0:GeneratedKeys/Entry/ID"/><target property="newRowID" type="property"/> </enrich> error is xpath cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that enrich mediator need namespace so

```
<enrich>
   <source clone="true" xmlns:n0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xpath="$body/n0:GeneratedKeys/n0:Entry/n0:ID"/>
   <target property="newRowID" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

did the magic ... So ALWAYS put a namespace lesson learned